# Likelihood function and the posterior distrubution of the Reed-Frost model

Tags: probability, bayesian, inference, likelihood

Consider the Reed-Frost epidemic model.

Consider the case where the available date consist of the final sizes of epidemics in households of three individuals, one of whom is initially infective. Our objective is to make inferences about the avoidance probability $q$. For $j=0,1,2$ let $n_j$ denote the number of households in which an epidemics of final size $j$ occurs, so that the data can be written $(n_0, n_1, n_2)$. Let $n_{21}$ denote the (unobserved) number of epidemics with pattern of infection given by $(1,1,1)$. The full likelihood function for q is thus 
$$
L(q;n_0, n_1, n_2, n_{21})= 2^{n_1 +n_{21}}
q^{2n_0 +2n_1 + n_{21}}(1-q)^{n_1+2n_2}.\qquad\qquad(1)
$$

Now denote  $\pi(\cdot|\cdot)$ to be a conditional distributions. We assume a priori that $q$ has a $Beta(\alpha, \delta)$ distribution from which it follows that the posterior distribution is given by
$$
\pi(q|n_0, n_1, n_2, n_{21})\sim Beta(2n_0 +2n_1 + n_{21}+\alpha, n_1+2n_2+\delta). \qquad\qquad(2)
$$

Next, by assuming independent behaviour of different households it follows that

$$
\pi(n_{21}|n_0, n_1, n_2, q)\sim Binomial\lbrace n_2, 2q/{2q+1}\rbrace. \qquad(3)
$$

Cans someone explain how they went from equation $(1) \rightarrow (2) \rightarrow (3)$?

Thank you.